# Why is SQLAlchemy only installing itself in my Python 2.7 library?

Tags: python, macos, sqlalchemy

I am on MacOS.

I am trying to write an ETL module for myself but I'm getting hung up on the fact that I cannot seem to get SQLAlchemy to install itself in my python 3.7 directory. It is installing itself fine in my 2.7 folder, even when I specify:

```
sudo pip3 install sqlalchemy
```

This is driving me nuts! I'd love any advice on the matter.

Below is what I am doing exactly:

```
User-MacBook-Pro:2.7 User$ pip3 install sqlalchemy --user
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting sqlalchemy
Installing collected packages: sqlalchemy
Successfully installed sqlalchemy-1.3.2
User-MacBook-Pro:2.7 User$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlalchemy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
>>> 
User-MacBook-Pro:2.7 User$ pip3 uninstall sqlalchemy
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Uninstalling SQLAlchemy-1.3.2:
  Would remove:
    /Users/User/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.3.2.dist-info/*
    /Users/User/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sqlalchemy/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled SQLAlchemy-1.3.2
User-MacBook-Pro:2.7 User$
```

Comment: The syntax error involving `inport` is just noise that distracts from your otherwise real problem.

Comment: Are you sure `pip3` is really the version of `pip` for Python 3, and not a symlink to `pip` somehow?

Comment: right, I'll edit that out syntax error with inport. It really doesn't work though, proper spelling done with no typos and all

Comment: @chepner how would I check for a symlink? I'm almost certain I didn't do anything with symlinks or aliai or whatever

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l $(which pip3)`?

Comment: '-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  286 Apr  9 13:37 /usr/local/bin/pip3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pip3 -V
```

which will give something like this

```
pip 19.0.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

so you can know where your pip installation is. As an alternative to install the given module you can try

```
python3 -m pip install sqlalchemy
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear; I am on MacOS. Doing 

`pip3 -v`

gives me a usage list

Comment: Changed `pip3 -v` to `pip3 -V`